# Add Chakra to Grub (installed by Mint)

Tags: grub, linux-mint

I have 4x30G partitions on my SSD. I installed Mint to the first one. Mint installed grub2 with it, which recognizes Win7 on a HDD as well, so I thought I keep this boot loader. I installed Chakra to the second partition without installing grub again. After rebooting Chakra did not show up in grub menu. Can I add it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

```
sudo update-grub
```

this updated the grub and found Chakra.

Comment: nice simple solution :-)