# Can't boot kali linux under grub2 (usb flash)

Tags: linux, boot, usb, grub, kali-linux

I split usb flash to three part:

**| For DATA | For Kali Linux | Persistence |**

Then i'm install grub on /dev/sdb2:

```
sudo grub-install --no-floppy --root-directory=/mnt/linux /dev/sdb
```

Write /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

```
...
menuentry "Live USB Persistence" {
    isofile=/iso/kali.iso
    bootoptions="findiso=$isofile boot=live noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali persistence"
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz $bootoptions
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
...
```

And copy kali.2.0.iso to /iso/kali.iso.

Then i reboot laptop in "usb_boot_mode" and grub menu has appear.
Then it writes "file not found" immidiatly if i choose "Kali persistence" (it's only 1 menu item).
If i press "e" (edit) and then press F10 (save and boot) without any changes, it  boot in something like sh, but without any X system or kali functionallity. Just command line with strange name.

What i did wrong? Maybe other grub-boot options? Other filesystem structure?

Answer (score 0):

Is this question answered here... [Add Chakra to Grub (installed by Mint)](https://superuser.com/questions/963240/add-chakra-to-grub-installed-by-mint/963263)

by

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: i can't update-grub coz i can't load in system!

Comment: ok - sorry that I misunderstood.... I will delete my unhelpful answer... sorry

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by re-download kali.iso image. Image was corrupted and sha1 sum was wrong.

All my settings are correct. You can use it in your grub.cfg